# Is it possible to raise exception that fail (and not error) test in pytest finalizer?

Tags: python, pytest

Note : I'm using the version 2.7.3 of pytest with old-style for fixture. I **have to** use this version at the moment. I'm using python 2.7 on Linux.

I currently working on tests with pytest that required a check at the end of each test. To proceed I have wrote a fixture with a finalizer which perform the check but when I raise an exception I have a strange result.

Here is the code (edited for SO, you can copy/paste to test):

```
# copy/past to foobar.py and run `python -m pytest -v foobar.py`
import pytest

def check():
    assert 0

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='function')
def fixture_foobar(request):
    def tear_down():
        check()

    request.addfinalizer(tear_down)

def test_ok():
    assert 1

def test_nok():
    assert 0
```

So the code currently works but the output looks weird and wrong :

```
# test pass and finalizer raise exception
# expected result : foobar.py::test_ok FAILED
foobar.py::test_ok PASSED
foobar.py::test_ok ERROR


# test fail and finalizer raise exception
# expected result : foobar.py::test_nok FAILED
foobar.py::test_nok FAILED
foobar.py::test_nok ERROR
```

The case where finaliser do nothing stay good.

So if somebody have a idea how to fix it. May be I don't have the good approach but finalizer sounds like a good idea.

Thanks.

**EDIT** : I have the same comportment with the `pytest_runtest_teardown` hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was not so hard.

Pytest provide a lot of [hooks](https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.7.3/_modules/_pytest/hookspec.html) and I have to use `pytest_pyfunc_call` which is run **after** test execution.

Solution :

```
# conftest.py
def check():
    assert 0

def pytest_pyfunc_call(pyfuncitem):
    check()


# test_foobar.py
def test_ok():
    assert 1

def test_nok():
    assert 0
```

And the result :

```
test_foobar.py::test_ok FAILED
test_foobar.py::test_nok FAILED
```

**Improve it :**

By default, if test failed and `check()` failed only the `AssertionError` of `check()` is traced. If I found a solution to ignore `check()` in case of test failure I'll update the answer. If you have a solution, you are welcome !